# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tag_name' When attempting to use selenium's "Select" in my pytest framework

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, pytest

Getting this error. I am using selenium with Python. Now sure why as every other function works

```
@pytest.mark.tcid21
def test_amazons(self):



 adlogs = Admin_logs(self.driver)
   amz.go_to_amazon()
   amz.dropdown()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tag_name'

[![amazon dropdown][1]][1]
```

main pytest file:

```
@pytest.mark.usefixtures("init_driver")


class Test_amazon:


    @pytest.mark.tcid21
    def test_amazons(self):


      amz = amazon(self.driver)


      amz.go_to_amazon()

      amz.dropdown()
```

file 2:

```
class amazon(AMAZON_LOCATORS):
    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver
        self.sl = SeleniumExtended(self.driver)

    def go_to_amazon(self):
       
        self.driver.get('https://www.amazon.co.uk/')


    def dropdown(self):
       
        dropdown = usernamee= (By.ID, 'searchDropdownBox')

        select_list = self.sl.wait_until_visibility_of_element(self.DROPDOWN)

        select = Select(select_list)
```

wait until visibility of element function (taken from a class from another file):

```
    def wait_until_visibility_of_element(self, locator, timeout=None):





        timeout= timeout if timeout else self.default_timeout
        try:
         WebDriverWait(self.driver, timeout).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(locator))
        except TimeoutException:
            raise Exception(f"Element: {locator} not displayed with after timeout of {timeout} ")
```

Let me know if you need more information. I didn't want to bloat this with too much code

locator class file (edited to added code formating):

```
class AMAZON_LOCATORS:
   

  DROPDOWN= (By.ID, 'searchDropdownBox')
```

Comment: where is `self.DROPDOWN` defined?

Comment: On a different file. I have now included it in the question

Comment: please add full stack traces if present in the output.